# My Array only goes up to 3 values and my second Array repeats whatever the user entered into the 2nd array

Tags: c++, vector, set-operations

I have changed up my code to be vectors. Now I am trying to find the Union, Intersection, and A-B. My code for both Union and Intersection now is working. I can not figure out how to do my difference. I figured I could take A and if it == to B then not insert it but it still puts them in none the less.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void Union();
void Intersection();
void Difference();

int main()
{
    Union();
    Intersection();
    Difference();


    return 0;
}

void SetVectors()
{

}


void Union()
{
        int temp = 0;
vector<int> U{};
vector<int> A{3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17};

vector<int> B{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++)
    {

        if (A[i] != B[j])
        {
            int temp = A[i];
            U.push_back(temp);
            temp = B[j];
            U.push_back(temp);
        }


              //Used To Sort The Vector So There Is No Duplicates And Its In Order!
              sort( U.begin(), U.end() );
              U.erase( unique( U.begin(), U.end() ), U.end() );
    }

}
cout << "Union: ";
for(int z = 0; z < U.size(); z++)
{
    cout << U[z] << " ";
}
}

void Intersection()
{
        int temp = 0;
vector<int> U{};
vector<int> A{3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 15};
//Used To Sort The Vector So There Is No Duplicates And Its In Order!
sort( A.begin(), A.end() );
A.erase( unique( A.begin(), A.end() ), A.end() );

vector<int> B{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
//Used To Sort The Vector So There Is No Duplicates And Its In Order!
sort( B.begin(), B.end() );
B.erase( unique( B.begin(), B.end() ), B.end() );



for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++)
    {

        if (A[i] == B[j])
        {
            int temp = A[i];
            U.push_back(temp);
            temp = B[j];
            U.push_back(temp);
        }


              //Used To Sort The Vector So There Is No Duplicates And Its In Order!
              sort( U.begin(), U.end() );
              U.erase( unique( U.begin(), U.end() ), U.end() );
    }

}
cout << "Intersection: ";
for(int z = 0; z < U.size(); z++)
{
    cout << U[z] << " ";
}
}

void Difference()
{
    int temp = 0;
    vector<int> D{};
    vector<int> A{3, 4, 9, 12, 13, 15};

    vector<int> B{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++)
        {

            if (A[i] == B[j])
            {
                cout << A[i];
            }
            else
            {
                int temp = A[i];
                D.push_back(temp);
            }


                  //Used To Sort The Vector So There Is No Duplicates And Its In Order!
                  sort( D.begin(), D.end() );
                  D.erase( unique( D.begin(), D.end() ), D.end() );
        }

    }
    cout << "Difference: ";
    for(int z = 0; z < D.size(); z++)
    {
        cout << D[z] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify an array's size after creation. Changing `MaxSizeA` does nothing to `A` and assigning to `A[0]` is "undefined behavior".

Comment: `int A [MaxSizeA];` is used when `MaxSizeA == 0`. That won't work. (you use   `MaxSizeA` before you ask the user what  `MaxSizeA` is) Further `int A [MaxSizeA];` (a *Variable Length Array*) is not part of the C++ standard and only provided by non-standard compiler extensions (in fact as of C11, it is optional for C compilers to support as well). Why are you using an array instead of [std::vector<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: In your `while(z < MaxSizeB)` loop, I suppose you want to use `B[z] = inputB;`.

Answer (score 1):

The best help we can provide is to say "Don't do it that way..." Continuing from the comment `int A [MaxSizeA];` is declared while `MaxSizeA` is zero attempting to declare an non-standard *Variable Length Array* (VLA) with zero elements. That won't work. For starters VLAs are not part of C++, and are only provided as non-standard compiler extensions by some compilers.

Bewilderingly, you `#include <vector>`, which is great -- that is what you want to use to store an unknown number of objects - but, you fail to make use of [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in your code.

Before looking at how you can use `std::vector` to accomplish what you are trying to do, take a quick look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696). Learning good habits early is a lot easier than breaking bad ones later.

**std::vector**

`std::vector` allows you to add as many objects to your collection as you like and the memory management is handled automatically. In your case you can ask for `MaxSizeA` and `MaxSizeB` and then loop until the user has provided that many *valid* elements for each. Take `A` for example, you could do:

```
#include <limits>
...
    std::vector<int> A{}, B{};
    size_t MaxSizeA, MaxSizeB;
    int val;
    
    std::cout << "How Many Values Do You Wish To Enter For A: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> MaxSizeA)) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (A.size() < MaxSizeA) {
        std::cout << "Enter Values For A[" << A.size() << "]: ";
        if (std::cin >> val)
            A.push_back(val);
        else {
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
```

Where you declare your vectors and variables local to `main()`, there is no reason to use *global* variables here (and in fact they should be avoided unless absolutely necessary). You prompt for `MaxSizeA` and then ***validate*** the stream-state after your call to `std::cin` to ensure you have a valid integer value in `MaxSizeA`. Then you simply loop until `A.size() == MaxSizeA` ensuring your user provided `MaxSizeA` valid integer inputs. You handle a failed input by resetting the stream state and then clearing to the end of input with `std::cin.ignore()`. No counter is needed, you can simple use `A.size()` and `B.size()` to determine the current number of elements stored in each vector.

(you can also check `std::cin.eof()` and `std::cin.bad()` to catch a user manually generating `EOF` or catch an unrecoverable stream error -- that is left to you.)

You can use a [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to output the contents of each vector, e.g.

```
    std::cout << "\narray A:\n";
    for (auto& v : A)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
```

Putting it altogether into an example similar to what your are attempting you would have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    
    std::vector<int> A{}, B{};
    size_t MaxSizeA, MaxSizeB;
    int val;
    
    std::cout << "How Many Values Do You Wish To Enter For A: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> MaxSizeA)) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (A.size() < MaxSizeA) {
        std::cout << "Enter Values For A[" << A.size() << "]: ";
        if (std::cin >> val)
            A.push_back(val);
        else {
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nHow Many Values Do You Wish To Enter For B: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> MaxSizeB)) {
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (B.size() < MaxSizeB) {
        std::cout << "Enter Values For B[" << B.size() << "]: ";
        if (std::cin >> val)
            B.push_back(val);
        else {
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "\narray A:\n";
    for (auto& v : A)
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    
    std::cout << "\narray B:\n";
    for (auto& v : B)
        std::cout << v << '\n';

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program and intentionally providing bad input to exercise the error handling you could do:

```
$ ./bin/arrayVLAtoVector
How Many Values Do You Wish To Enter For A: 4
Enter Values For A[0]: 10
Enter Values For A[1]: 20
Enter Values For A[2]: thirty
  error: invalid integer input.
Enter Values For A[2]: 30
Enter Values For A[3]: 40

How Many Values Do You Wish To Enter For B: 3
Enter Values For B[0]: 1
Enter Values For B[1]: 2
Enter Values For B[2]: buckle my shoe
  error: invalid integer input.
Enter Values For B[2]: 3

array A:
10
20
30
40

array B:
1
2
3
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.